# grunt-connect-proxy not catching requests?

Tags: javascript, proxy, gruntjs

I am working on an app, and someone else is responsible for developing the API. It lives on a different machine completely, but when I try to ping it I get CORS errors. I need to set up `http-proxy` so that I can get around it. For this I'm using `grunt-connect-proxy`.

Problem is that my requests aren't getting caught and so they're not hitting the API.

```
connect : {
    options : {

        port             : 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname         : '0.0.0.0',
        // hostname         : 'localhost',
        livereload       : 35729,
        useAvailablePort : true,

    },
    livereload : {
        options: {
            open : true,
            base : [
                '.tmp',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>'
            ],

            middleware: function (connect, options) {
                if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
                    options.base = [options.base];
                }

                // Setup the proxy
                var middlewares = [require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest];

                // Serve static files.
                options.base.forEach(function(base) {
                    middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
                });

                // Make directory browse-able.
                var directory = options.directory || options.base[options.base.length - 1];
                middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));

                return middlewares;
            }

        },
    },
    test : {
        options: {
            port : 9021,
            base : [
                '.tmp',
                'test',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>'
            ]
        }
    },
    dist : {
        options : {
            base : '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
    },
    proxies : [{
        context      : '/api',
        host         : '10.0.4.121',
        port         : 8443,
        https        : true,
        changeOrigin : false,
        rewrite : {
            '/api' : '/evidence/api/v2/ui/'
        }
    }]
},
```

When I run `grunt serve` and try out some AJAX calls, they are still going to `http://localhost:9000/api/etc`. This is the raw header from Fiddler:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/api/ping/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:9000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I posted enough relevant information. I'm not trying to vampire here but I really don't know how to proceed

Comment: IMO it is fine, request is going there but hit external server, try to return something on 10.0.4.121